# Open URL in WKWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview, urlencode

I am trying to open following URL in WKWebview,

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/mynameisanthony@gmail.com?secret=B6S2LGJTQHIDKIMU&issuer=someapp+Auth

```
        strQRImage =  @"https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/mynameisanthony@gmail.com?secret=B6S2LGJTQHIDKIMU&issuer=someapp+Auth";
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strQRImage];
        [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

when I run this code it gives nil value in url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters** to make it a valid URL.

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/mynameisanthony@gmail.com?secret=B6S2LGJTQHIDKIMU&issuer=someapp+Auth";
NSString *encodedURLString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedURLString];
```

Now you can use this url.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Arora

Comment: @SomePerson you can upvote and accept the answer if your issue is resolved

Comment: I have Up voted  but seein this Message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."
Ask SO, if you want to increase upvote of your Answer

Answer (score 0):

Thats probably because your URL is not valid and contains invalid characters. You should make sure that the url is properly encoded.

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved my issue.

```
        strQRImage = [strQRImage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "];
        strQRImage = [strQRImage stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[strQRImage stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]]];
```